# ping 8.8.8.8 and DNS fails despite healthy connection to router and good DNS settings

Tags: networking, network-manager

An Ubuntu machine can successfully connect to the router on either 2.4GHz or 5GHz.

The connection information looks good. I've tried automatic DNS, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, and several others.

It can't just be DNS either as `ping 8.8.8.8` has 100% packet loss. Other devices connected to the same router have no connectivity issues.

The results of `iwconfig` and `ifconfig` look healthy to me (I'd paste, but I'm writing this from a different computer). I've also toggled the interface on and off many times.

I've also tried rebooting. What else can I try to establish a working Internet connection?

Comment: You can use `traceroute 8.8.8.8` to actually see at what point it fails.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Thanks. Seems `traceroute` is actually not installed. I should've thought to install it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar situation and solved by changing DNS.
You can try changing any other DNS. 
Try `1.1.1.1` DNS it's new and fast. Hope changing DNS will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it just now, but no luck. It's probably not DNS because `ping 8.8.8.8` (or ping whatever IP) doesn't use DNS since the IP is already known, but that kind of `ping` still fails for me.